# Error while finding hidden layer activations in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am trying to find out activations for the hidden layer in an autoencoder unit using keras the model runs fine but when I try to find out the hidden activation it throws an error relating to CUDA then kernel dies and restarts.

> Keras version 2.0.8

```
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# Fit regression DNN model.
print("Creating/Training neural network")
# this is your initial model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(400, input_dim=x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(x.shape[1])) # Multiple output neurons
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x,x,verbose=0,epochs=100)

print("Score neural network")
pred = model.predict(x)
```

the code to get hidden layer activations

```
import keras.backend as K
def get_activations(model, layer, X_batch):
    get_activations = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[layer].output])
    activations = get_activations([X_batch,0])
    return activations
my_featuremaps =get_activations(model, 1, x)
```

Error that conda prompt throws up

```
2018-01-29 17:54:21.660022: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
2018-01-29 17:54:22.275065: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1030] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GT 740M major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0325
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.66GiB
2018-01-29 17:54:22.275240: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 740M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)
2018-01-29 17:54:29.032758: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GT 740M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)

2018-01-29 17:57:54.356314: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_driver.cc:1228] failed to enqueue async memcpy from host to device: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED; GPU dst: 00000005014FFC00; host src: 000001A08A1AF040; size: 3136000=0x2fda00
2018-01-29 17:57:54.356669: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\stream.cc:306] Error recording event in stream: error recording CUDA event on stream 000001A0654E1060: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED; not marking stream as bad, as the Event object may be at fault. Monitor for further errors.
2018-01-29 17:57:54.357151: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_event.cc:49] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED
```

Comment: What is the size of your `x`?

Comment: x is of size 1000,784 .1000 rows and 784 columns @MarcinMożejko